# Prove or disprove: if $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuous point at 0 then $g(x)$ = $x*f(x)$ is differentiable at 0

Tags: calculus, limits, derivatives, continuity

I need to determine whether it is true that if $f(x)$ has a removable discontinuous point at 0 then $g(x)$ = $x*f(x)$ is differentiable at 0.

I thought to prove it by proving that $g(x)$ is continuous from both positive and negative directions by saying that the limit of $f(x)$ from both positive and negative directions is equal and, because the function $h(x) = x$ is continuous. which will lead me to say that $g(x)$ is continuous and then find the derivative.

But I'm not sure if it's possible to claim that.

Comment: Is $f$ discontinuous or has a removable singularity?  The title and text don’t match.  Also, if it’s a removable discontinuity, the question should really be (after replacing the singularity) if $f$ is continuous at zero, is $xf$ differentiable at zero.

Comment: After you ask a question here, if you get an acceptable answer, you should "accept" the answer by clicking the check mark $\checkmark$ next to it. This scores points for you and for the person who answered your question. You can find out more about accepting answers here: [How do I accept an answer?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3286/), [Why should we accept answers?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3399/), [What should I do if someone answers my question?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

*Here, it is worth just going back to the definition of a derivative as a limit.*

By definition of a removable discontinuity, we have that $f$ is defined at $0$ and that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ exists, *but* $f(0) \neq \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$.

Now, for $g$ as in the question, we have $g(0)=0\cdot f(0)=0$ by definition.

For $x\neq 0$, we can write
$$
\frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = \frac{g(x)}{x} = \frac{xf(x)}{x} = f(x)
$$
so $\lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0}$ exists since $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x)$ does. It follows that $g$ is differentiable at $0$, with
$$
g'(0) = \lim_{x\to 0} \frac{g(x)-g(0)}{x-0} = \lim_{x\to 0} f(x)
$$

Comment: So, what if f(x) = (sinx)/x ? now f is not defined at 0 so g(0) is not defined at 0 neither.

Comment: @Yair $f$ has to be defined at zero, otherwise it does not have a removable discontinuity. $f(0)$ can be literally any number, but it has to exist.

Answer (score 0):

To see that $g$ is differentiabile at $0$, we calculate the limit $$\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{g\left(0+h\right)-g\left(0\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{\left(0+h\right)\cdot f\left(0+h\right) - 0\cdot f\left(0\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0}\frac{h\cdot f\left(h\right)}{h}=\lim_{h\to 0} f\left(h\right)$$
So, $f'(0)$ exists.